# Ember.js Component Uncaught #<error>

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Using [Yeoman Ember Generator](https://github.com/yeoman), I tried to create a new block component, e.g:

```
//directory: template/components/test-component.hbs

Test-component's content: <div>{{yield}}</div>
```

And to be called in application template:

```
//directory: template/application.hbs

<div id="application_content">
    {{#test-component}}yield content{{/test-component}}
</div>
```

The weird thing is when its compiled using grunt and handlebars runtime, it produce an **error** says:

```
Uncaught #<error>
```

When I tried to not use handlebars runtime and instead move all templates to be inline in index.html, it works fine. Does Yeoman Ember Generator does not support components? Or are there any other way to fix this?

**EDIT:**

Here's the example of the error when it's already precompiled: http://jsfiddle.net/dekaa/wyQ84/ and here's when I move it into inline code: http://jsfiddle.net/dekaa/LcSSE/

Comment: You should be able to see what it's getting injected into the page as.  It does support components.

Comment: The page doesn't load anything. Yes, it does support basic component like just {{test-component}}, but when I change it into block level component {{#test-component}}content{{/test-component}} it shows this error.

Comment: I meant in the network response, my bad.

Comment: Hi Kingpin2k, see my edited section above.